# Batch command to pull variables from a text file

Tags: batch-file

Is there any command for a batch file to read a text file, and use the content as a variable? A while back I'd heard about a command that could read the last line of a text file and assign this as a variable in the batch file, but I can't remember what the command was or if it even worked. Is there such a command? I've tried things like:

```
Set /a var < directory.bat\file.txt
```

which returns a value of 0, or

```
Set /p var < directory.bat\file.txt
```

or

```
Set /i var < directory.bat\file.txt
```

, which gives the error "the syntax of a command is incorrect. Am I on the right track with "set" commands, or is there a completely different command for this (or will I have to write an entire different, multi-line script to do this)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set /p var=<directory\file.txt`

that will grab the first line out of a text document.

Comment: cool, a for loop should work too: `FOR /F %i IN (file.txt) DO SET VAR=%i`

Comment: If there was only one line in the text file then it will do the same thing. However, if there are multiple lines in the text file it will set the **last** line to the variable. Sometimes this can cause problems, if there is a blank line at the very end of the file, as well as with delayed expansion.

Comment: @unclemeat, you can always check the variable if its defined or not a null string.

Comment: @brianadams That's right. something like this should do it - `FOR /F %i IN (file.txt) DO IF "%i" NEQ "" SET VAR=%i`.

Comment: It's not super robust, but it will quickly and easily get the variable and avoid the issue with possible blank lines at the end of the file.

Comment: @unclemeat that first answer was what I was looking for. What does %i indicate in the second code?

Comment: @Boone If you're interested, take a look at how For loops work in batch. `%i` (can be any letter) is a temporary variable that exists within the for loop. Since you're using `/F` and pointing it at a file, in each iteration of the loop `%i` will be the current line of that file. If there are deliminating characters (i.e. a space) then the string will be broken up - if you had the string 'hello world', `%i` would be 'hello' and `%j` would be 'world', unless you specify a different deliminator. Note that a single % symbol is used from the command line, where as two (%%i) are used in a batch file

Comment: @unclemeat How exactly to for loops work in Batch? I've looked around, but I can't seem to understand it. Is the purpose of the For loop to be a multi-purpose loop, or is it to be used specifically for pulling contents out of a file?

Comment: @Boone http://ss64.com/nt/for.html It's multipurpose. You can loop through the output of a command, through a directory listing, check out that link.

Answer (score 4):

The classic form of this operation is

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do set var=%%a
```

which will set `var` to the entire contents of the last non-blank line.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do set var=%%a&goto next
:next
```

will set `var` to the first non-blank line

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do set var=%%a&call :process
...
:process
 echo var=%var%
goto :eof
```

will execute a subroutine with `var` set to each non-blank line in turn.

Without sample data, it's not possible to detemine which form suits your situation.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
set str=^&Type file.txt
echo %str%
```

Answer (score 1):

here's an awk command you can use

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('awk "!/^$/{s=$0}END{print s}" myFile.txt') do (
    echo last line is %%a
)
```

you can download awk [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cja5mvymvinmfco/mHw6J4I1Kd) or [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)